# React Native (View) onLayout does not execute functions

Tags: reactjs, view, height, native

I've been trying to get some values from the onLayout prop in a View component.

This is the View that gets returned in the render function:

```
<View onLayout={this.onLayout}>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</View>
```

Then this is the onLayout function that is in the same class

```
onLayout = () => {
  console.log("hello")
}
```

The console log is never done. But if I call `console.log("hello")` from within the onLayout prop it does show in the console.

```
<View onLayout={console.log("Hello")}>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</View>
```

This has had me mindblown for the past 4 hours. I've tried everything I could find here on stackoverflow and GitHub.

Am I just doing something very wrong?

Comment: In the case where you are writing onLayout = {console.log('hello')}, the console.log gets executed while the render is called and thus its return value is assigned to onLayout, this means onLayout is being assigned undefined even though hello will be shown on the screen at the render call !

Comment: to clarify the above comment, if you wanted to write to the console, you have to provide a function that does that ... so onLayout(() => {console.log("Hello")})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onLayout(event) {
    const {x, y, height, width} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    const newHeight = this.state.view2LayoutProps.height + 1;
    const newLayout = {
        height: newHeight ,
        width: width,
        left: x,
        top: y,
      };

    this.setState({ view2LayoutProps: newLayout });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.View1}>
          <Text>{this.state.view2LayoutProps.height}</Text>
        </View>
        <View onLayout={(event) => this.onLayout(event)} 
              style={[styles.View2, this.state.view2LayoutProps]} />
        <View style={styles.View3} />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Very strange but thank you a lot. Do you have any idea as to why this works and how I had it does not?